# Impossível ler dado do Array

Tags: angularjs, funções, controller

Estou tendo problemas no código abaixo não está conseguindo ler o valor $scope.ids[i].id, segue código:

```
$scope.carregarEnderecos = function (id) {
    $scope.repeateEnderecos = [];
    $http.post(url_sistema + 'estabelecimento/listar_enderecos', {'id': id}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data !== '0') {
            $scope.repeateEnderecos = data;
            $scope.ids = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                $scope.ids.push({'id':data[i].local_id});
            console.log($scope.ids);
            }
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.telefonesEnderecos();
            }, 5000);
            $scope.existeendereco = true;
        } else {
            $scope.repeateEnderecos = 0;
            $scope.existeendereco = false;
        }
    }).error(function (data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        alert(data);
    });
};

$scope.telefonesEnderecos = function () {
    $http.post(url_sistema + 'estabelecimento/telefones').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data !== '0') {
            $scope.telefones_enderecos = data;


            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            var tel = $scope.telefones_enderecos[i].fk_local_empresa;
             if ($scope.ids[i].id === tel) {
                console.log("deu");
            } else {
                console.log("nao deudeu");
            }
        }
    }).error(function (data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        alert(data);
    });
};
```

Comment: Qual função é chamada primeiro? A "carregarEnderecos" ou "telefonesEnderecos"? Porque o $scope.ids é preenchido na função "carregarEnderecos". Outra coisa, o seu ciclo "for" dentro da função "telefonesEnderecos" não tem chavetas "{ ... }" logo ele só vai incluir no ciclo for a linha abaixo, o "if" não vai entrar, logo a sua var "tel" será sempre igual a última posição do array "telefones_enderecos". Se isso for assim, então não precisa do ciclo "for", bastava colocar var tel = $scope.telefones_enderecos[data.length-1].fk_local_empresa;

Comment: Obrigado por comentar mas não vou mais precisar utilizar esta forma de tratamento pois não vai ser mais usada a ferramenta que estava sendo desenvolvida, foi solicitado o desenvolvimento de outra forma, mas mesmo assim agradeço por querer ajudar, tenha um ótimo dia Filipe, obrigado mesmo